# LocalStorage- not able to remove items from todo list

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage

I've recently started to work my Todo list without relying on coding tutorials and it's so difficult. I'm able to add items in my list, but I'm not able to remove items. When I click on items, all items gets deleted. Could you help please?

```
   <fieldset>
      <legend class="task-list-title">Goals that I need to work on</legend>
        <input
         id="inpKey" 
         type="text"
         placeholder="add new goal"
         aria-label="new list name"
    <button type="button" id="btnInsert">New Goal</button>
    <div id="task_list">

    </div>
</fieldset>
```

JavaScript Code

```
const inpKey  = document.getElementById("inpKey");
const btnInsert = document.getElementById("btnInsert");
const task_list = document.getElementById("task_list");

btnInsert.onclick = function() {
const key = inpKey.value;
   if(key) {
     localStorage.setItem(key, inpKey.value);
     location.reload();
     }
}

for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
const key = localStorage.key(i);
task_list.innerHTML += `${key}<br />`
}

task_list.onclick = function() { 
  for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  const key = localStorage.key(i);
  window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
  task_list.innerHTML = key; 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: I think the main issue is that it's difficult to find which list item is clicked as you are storing your list as string something like `abc<br/>xyz<br/>`. Now when we want to delete abc and click on it, actually the whole string is getting clicked `abc<br/>xyz<br/>` so its difficult to find which localStorage key needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe the problem was you not checking for which particular todo to delete, instead you were deleting them all

```
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    const key = localStorage.key(i);
   // I it would be better if you wrapped each key in its own element
    task_list.innerHTML += `<div>${key}</div>`; // I'm using a `div` so there'll be no need for a `<br/>` tag
}   

task_list.onclick = function(e) {
    // I want to use the event data to find out exactly which localStorage key to delete
    for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        const key = localStorage.key(i);
        // Here i'm checking if the key is the same as the todo that you want to delete
        if (key == e.target.innerText) {
            localStorage.removeItem(key); // Removing the todo from storage
            e.target.remove(); // Removing the todo element from the DOM
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Appending the new key to the `innerHTML` for `tasks_list` makes it very difficult to get the key when you want to delete the item. Instead it would be easier to make each new task a `<p>` element (or an unordered list element) and to append that new element as a child to `tasks_list` like so-

```
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  const key = localStorage.key(i);
  const newTask = document.createElement('p') //create a new html element
  newTask.classList.add('task') //add a class of "task" to it
  newTask.innerHTML = key //set the innerHTML to equal the key
  task_list.appendChild(newTask) //add the newTask element as a child element of task_list
}
```

You can add event listeners to each element with the `task` class by looping through each and adding your event listener. The nice thing here is that when you want the key for an individual task you need only grab the `innerHTML` and use that-

```
for(let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    tasks[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        const key = tasks[i].innerHTML
        window.localStorage.removeItem(key)
        location.reload()
    })
}
```

The way you currently removed items by looping through `localStorage` was actually removing an element on each pass through of the loop and not checking to see if the item it was removing was the item that had been clicked.

EDIT- a. mola's answer does something similar to mine but you don't need to loop through the entirety of local storage to find your matching key. That's the beauty of having key/value pairs! As long as you know the key you can manipulate the data without having to first search for it through a loop.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Andrew